# How to detect timezone abbreviation using date-fns-tz?

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs, date-formatting, date-fns

I want to print **timeZone abbreviation** like: IST, UTC, PST, MST, CST, EST, etc...

I'm migrating my code from momentJS to date-fns and having the following issue. When I was using momentJS everything was working as expected. For example, the code below will print "**IST**"

```
const timeZone = 'Asia/Calcutta';
moment.tz(new Date(), timeZone).format('z'); // IST
```

[Demo using MomentJS](https://stackblitz.com/edit/timezone-eo9ng5)

Now my code using **date-fns** works but not all the way because it prints **"India Standard Time"** and I only want to print **IST**.

```
format(parisDate, 'zzzz', { timeZone: 'Asia/Calcutta', locale: enGB }); // India Standard Time
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing or doing wrong?
Here's a live demo of my code: [**date-fns DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/date-fns-playground-16wtxv)

Comment: Interesting question. I found a solution but can't explain why... You should import a different locale (default is en-US). 
Importing `import enGB from 'date-fns/locale/en-GB'` and then changing to `const zoneString = format(utcToZonedTime(new Date(), timeZone), 'zzz', {locale: enGB});` on your example will do the job. I cannot however understand why the timezone abbreviation is tied with the library's locales. I will read the docs and maybe upload a proper answer.

Comment: @antoniom I imported what you suggested and also made the changes but it prints "GMT+5:30". It doesn't work

Comment: Strange... works for me... Have a look here https://github.com/marnusw/date-fns-tz#format

Comment: @antoniom are you printing "India Standard Time" or IST"? I want to print "IST"

Comment: Please retry once more using 'en-IN' as locale. And upgrade date-fns to the latest version (2.16.1)

Answer (score 4):

After examining the `date-fns-tz`'s code it turns out that it does not generate the timezone abbreviation's by itself but it uses the browser's Intl API. Timezone abbreviations differ from locale to locale.
Locales such as 'en-US' or 'en-GB' do not include IST as timezone abbreviation while 'en-IN' does.
You therefore need to

```
import enIN from 'date-fns/locale/en-IN'
```

and then pass it as a 3rd agument on your `format` call
i.e.

```
import { utcToZonedTime, format } from "date-fns-tz";
const timeZone = "Asia/Kolkata"
const zoneString = format(utcToZonedTime(new Date(), timeZone), "zzz", {
  timeZone,
  locale: enIN
});
```

This however does not guarantee that other abbreviations (e.g. CET) will work with the proposed locale

Comment: Your current solution works ONLY for India. Because if timeZone = 'Europe/Paris' the value of zoneString is GMT+1 instead of printing "CEST". Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to import everyting from date-fns/locale at once something like date-fns/locale/* ?

Comment: I am afraid that you cannot achieve the desired effect. It seems that different locales return different abbreviated timezones. For example my country's locale ('el' / Greece) copes well with every European timezone (CEST, EET etc) but not with IST or EST.

Comment: momentJS is able to accomplish this task but for some reason it seems to be tricky with date-fns

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but `moment-timezone` seems to be using lookup tables in order to report "IST". That's a totally different technique

Comment: I'm not entirely sure on that one.