# Format timezone as PST, EST, etc for date-fns

Tags: date, timezone, date-formatting, date-fns, date-fns-tz

I'm using [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/v2.30.0/docs/format) to format my date objects when displaying to the user. I need to display their local timezone but I want it to display timezones as `PST`, or `EST`, etc., but all I get are `GMT-4`, `GMT-7`, etc.

Right now my format string is:

```
FORMAT_DATETIME="MMMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"
```

**NOTE**: I did some reading and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65416339/how-to-detect-timezone-abbreviation-using-date-fns-tz) but it's been 2 years so I'm not sure if things have changed.